# Show/Prove these integrals are equal

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have been trying to evaluate both integrals supposing that if their derivatives are equal then they are equal, but I have gotten nowhere

$$\int _x^1 \frac {1}{1+t^2}\,dt =  \int _1^\frac{1}{x} \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dx\,dt$$

Comment: Just substitute $$y=\frac{1}{t}$$ in the equation on the left and see what you get.

Comment: What is your try?

Comment: Are there some mistakes in the differential? $dxdt$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

with the substitution $t=\frac {1}{u} $,

the first integral becomes

$$\int_\frac {1}{x}^1\frac {1}{1+\frac {1}{u^2}}(-\frac {1}{u^2}) du$$

You can take it.

> with derivative.
>   For $x>0$,

derivative of left integral $=$
$$f'(x)=-\frac {1}{1+x^2} $$
derivative of the right integral $=$
$$g'(x)=\frac {1}{1+\frac {1}{x^2}}(-\frac {1}{x^2}) $$
$$=-\frac{1}{1+x^2} $$
thus
$$f (x)=g (x)+C $$
but
$$f (1)=g (1)\implies C=0.$$